# Imagemagick in WPN-XM

Tags: server, imagemagick, localhost, imagick, wpn-xm

I need to use Imagemagick in a testing site, so I have installed the WPN-XM server stack because it already have the Imagemagick built-in. I have used the latest version 0.86 x64 Full Installation. But, when I go into the control panel I cannot find any trace of Imagemagick. The folder imagemagick exists, so it is installed. But how I can active it in WPN-XM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to enable it, because ImageMagick is not a server or a daemon.
Its a set of command line tools to create, edit, compose, or convert images.
That's why there is no integration in the Server-Control-Panel.

PHP has an extension ImageMagick, which we installed into the PHP extension folder. When you enable this extension ImageMagick related functions are added to PHP. Before you can work with it, you would have to enable it first in `php.ini`, beause its `off` by default.

---

Please take a look at the ImageMagick docs how to work with the CLI tools:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php

If you need an webinterface on-top of the individual CLI commands use MagickStudio:
http://www.imagemagick.org/MagickStudio/scripts/MagickStudio.cgi